# SAS: Merge or join and retain all records while filling missing

Tags: sql, join, merge, sas, matching

I'm essentially splitting a dataset into two (those that have an ID and those that are missing ID), and merging the missing back into the non-missing by a set of match keys to help fill the ID. I have five total records below, and the final dataset needs to maintain all five records. Below is an example:

```
DATA TEST;
    LENGTH ID MKEY $12.;
    INPUT ID $ MKEY $;
    DATALINES;
    .   M123
    .   M456
    A   M123
    B   M456
    C   M789
    ;
RUN;

DATA MPOOL CPOOL; SET TEST;
    IF ID IN ("","0") THEN DO;
        MISS_ID = 1;
        OUTPUT MPOOL;
    END;
    ELSE DO;
        MISS_ID = 0; 
        OUTPUT CPOOL;
    END;
RUN;
```

So we end up merging the missing data `MPOOL`:

```
.   M123
.   M456
```

with the non-missing data `CPOOL`:

```
A   M123
B   M456
C   M789
```

Merging only gives me three records back, but I need to maintain all records and fill the missing (note that through the MKEY, we should be to link A and B records to missing IDs) as shown below:

```
A   M123
A   M123
B   M456
B   M456
C   M789
```

What kind of `SQL JOIN` would allow me to keep all records and fill the missing with those that have been successfully joined? Seems feasible but `MERGE` with this data never retains all records. I know I can lag/retain/fill in this example, but the big data I'm working with requires merging/joining due to other factors.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `union all` and `join`:

```
proc sql;
    select c.id, c.mkey
    from cpool c
    union all
    select c.id, m.mkey
    from mpool m join
         cpool c
         on m.mkey = c.mkey;
```

Comment: This looks promising Gordon, thank you. I'm getting warnings that say

`WARNING: A table has been extended with null columns to perform the UNION ALL set operation.
WARNING: Column named MKEY is duplicated in a select expression (or a view). Explicit references
         to it will be to the first one.`
`WARNING: Variable MKEY already exists on file WORK.MERGED.`

Comment: @Foxer  . . . Does this affect the results?

Comment: Yes, I'm expecting 233,836 records and only outputting 233,598 records -- a difference of 238 records which is puzzling.

Comment: @Foxer . . . That would probably be non-matching keys.  Use `left join` in the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Also try to use data step to fill in ID.

```
proc sort data=test;
by mkey  descending id;
run;

data want;
   set test;
   retain temp;
   by mkey id notsorted;
   if first.mkey then temp=id;
   if missing(id) then id=temp;
   drop temp;
run;
```

Comment: I mentioned in my description that I know I can use retain for this example to make it work, but I need to use merge/join due to multiple other variables and factors.